# NSIS - EnvVarUpdate overwrites system path when path is too long, is there a workaround?

Tags: windows, path, nsis

Here is my simple code:

```
!include "EnvVarUpdate.nsh"

Outfile "text.exe"

Section

${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "C:\Program Files\something"

SectionEnd
```

I understand that the "A" argument means this should APPEND the last argument to system path. However, testing this revealed that it overwrote my Path variable. Further tests reveal this is because Path was too long (>1024 chars, per the tutorial).

Is there a "safe" way to append to Path then? I am looking for a function that will append if Path is short enough, otherwise do nothing and report an error, something of that sort. I'm wondering if a standard method of doing this already exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have encountered some problems with path modifications from NSIS installers due to the fact that the default string management is limited to 1024 bytes and that string manipulations involved in path modification is truncating strings to 1024 and that is sometimes braking workstation environment (especially in development hosts where many tools are installed). BTW, There are many nsis built setups in the wild that are suffering from this problem.

We are using some different code derived from the `AddToPath` function from [Path manipulation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Path_Manipulation) but the problem stays similar.

The best workaround that we are using until now is by using the special build of NSIS that provides the large string support (of 8kB instead of 1 kB). That build is available in the [special builds page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds) of the NSIS wiki.

Comment: I tried building my nsi with makensis (special string build), got an error about "LogicLib.nsh" not found? (This is included in EnvVarUpdate.nsh) Where can I download this and other nsh dependencies, or am I just doing this wrong? Thanks

Comment: @mage: THis is weird, `LogicLib.nsh` is a file from the nsis installtion in the `include` directory.

Comment: I think I figured out, I think it was because NSIS directory was not in my Path, thank you though :) One more follow-up, with the new build, will Path be overwritten if it is greater than 8192 chars then? Is this a concern (and if not, why)?

Comment: @mage: yes, the problem is only moved, but if a path greater than 1 kB is common for example for a developer, a path greater than 8 kB is unlikely to be seen (but I guess still possible in theory?)

Comment: my friends tell me stories of people who had path vars that were that long, so it is possible to encounter. I don't know if you are a contributor to nsis, but do you know why is it that string length must be limited?

Comment: @mage: The NSIS code base was made by WinAMP guys with the principe "Keep it simple", so I suppose that fixed width strings avoid some problems like memory allocation. I am not a contributor of the trunk, but I have made some plugins and I use my own build of NSIS 2.46 where I use the 8kB strings and another option to produce an advanced log file during execution. If you really need to, you can build your own copy from sources with an increased string len, it is quite simple (a simple `#define`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Section 

ReadEnvStr $0 PATH
StrCpy $0 "$0;C:\Program Files\something"
StrLen $1 $0

${if} $1 < 1024
${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "C:\Program Files\something"
${else}
messagebox mb_ok "error writing environment variable"
${endIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: This does not work. It still overwrites if Path is too long. I think it's because NSIS strings are a max of 1024 characters, so it is not possible for the strlen to be greater than 1024 chars. So unless it is exactly 1024 chars, the if statement's condition will be true...